# Can't start Clinic.js, what should I do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, nest

At startup: `clinic doctor --on-port 'autocannon -m POST localhost:8000/users/register' -- node dist/main.js`

Gives help log:
Clinic.js Doctor - v9.2.0

clinic doctor is the first step in profiling your application.
It will show you what kind of problem you are having and recommend the path
forward.

To run clinic doctor

```
clinic doctor -- node server.js
```

Once you exit (Ctrl-C) the process, your report will open in a browser window. You can disable this behavior:

```
clinic doctor --open=false -- node server.js
```

If profiling on a server, it can be useful to only do data collection:

```
clinic doctor --collect-only -- node server.js
```

You can then transfer the data and visualize it locally:

```
clinic doctor --visualize-only PID.clinic-doctor-sample
```

You can use the --autocannon flag to simulate load on your server.
--autocannon accepts configuration for autocannon using "subarg" syntax:

```
clinic doctor --autocannon [ -m POST /api/example ] -- node server.js
```

When configuring --autocannon, the $PORT environment variable contains the
port your server is listening on:

```
clinic doctor --autocannon [ -m POST 'http://localhost:$PORT/?\$page=1' ] -- node server.js
```

Note that dollar signs ($) appearing in the URL must be escaped, else they
will be treated as environment variables as well.

Flags
-h | --help                Display Help
-v | --version             Display Version
--collect-only             Do not process data on termination
--visualize-only datapath  Build or rebuild visualization from data
--sample-interval interval Sample interval in milliseconds
--on-port                  Run a script when the server starts listening on a port.
--autocannon               Run the autocannon benchmarking tool when the server starts listening on a port.
--open                     Boolean to enable or disable your report opening in your web browser.
--dest                     Destination for the collected data (default .clinic/).

OS: Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Powershell to run it, it will not work. I don't know why exactly but I had the same issue. it's working fine with CMD.

Comment: Didn't work in Git Bash too. It is possible to run CMD from Explorer by typing "CMD" in the address bar.

Comment: @Abdul Razzaq: you have to put -- into quotes like "--" or '--' in oder to run it with Powershell